# What is the benefit of convoy-glusterfs over pure glusterfs

Tags: docker, glusterfs, rancher, convoy

I have a problem to see the benefit of glusterfs with convoy over pure glusterfs

Our starting position:

- we just use convoy of rancher, nothing else
- we have glusterfs setup for persistent data

Setup without convoy

- Mount glusterfs volume on each docker host
- create services with docker swarm and mount them to the right directory on the host, which hosts in the background to glusterfs

Setup with convoy

- Run the convoy deamon on ever dockerhost (which mounts the glusterfs volume in the background)
- create services with docker swarm and attach a volume to it over the convoy
- volume-driver, which is maped to a glusterfs directory in the background

So, what is the benefit of starting a deamon (convoy), which does the mounting in the background, when I can do the mounting myself over /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

- snapshots
- described in the docker compose / stack yaml file of your project.